# PHP - Attributing a value to a var depending on the value of another var

Tags: php, post, if-statement, var

I'm trying to attribute a value to a var depending of its text value.
I can't just attribute the numerical value directly (via my form) because i'm also saving in my database the text value.

```
$section = $_POST['section']; // required
$page = $_POST['page']; // required

if ($_POST['page'] == 'Template') { $Code == '00'; }
elseif ($_POST['page'] == 'Menu') { $Code == '01'; }
elseif ($_POST['page'] == 'Home Page') { $Code == '02'; }
elseif ($_POST['page'] == 'About Us') { $Code == '03'; }
elseif ($_POST['page'] == 'Contact Us') { $Code == '04'; }

$Code_Page = $Code.''.$section;
```

Exemple, the code for the section 18 of the Home Page is 0218.

I don't understand why it doesn't work ? 
Only the second part is saved ($section), not the first 2 numbers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so if I may ask , what is the question

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to ask the question. Why it doesn't work ? Only the second part is saved ($section), not the first 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `$Code` declaration first

```
$section = $_POST['section']; // required
$page = $_POST['page']; // required
$Code = ''; // This was missing 

if ($_POST['page'] == 'Template') { $Code == '00'; }
elseif ($_POST['page'] == 'Menu') { $Code == '01'; }
elseif ($_POST['page'] == 'Home Page') { $Code == '02'; }
elseif ($_POST['page'] == 'About Us') { $Code == '03'; }
elseif ($_POST['page'] == 'Contact Us') { $Code == '04'; }

$Code_Page = $Code.''.$section;
```

Comment: Thank you for your Help, declaring my var first and removing the double equals fixed the problem. I think i need to read again the manual of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Author has clarified what he is after now. I've kept the original answer in as I feel it is a better solution.

To define a variable in PHP, you use a single equals sign (=). You've used two equals signs (==) when defining *$Code*, which is a [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

**Original answer:**

I'm assuming that you wish to optimize this code. If so, I feel the best way to do so is to either create an array, or pull from the database you mentioned from. Once you have the dataset in an array, you can do some simple checking:

Static array method:

```
$pages = array('Template' => '00', 'Menu' => '01', 'Home Page' => '02', 'About Us' => '03', 'Contact' => '04');
if (in_array($_POST['Page'], $pages))
{
    //We have a match, deal with output here
    $Code_Page = $pages[$_POST['Page']].$section
}
else
{
    //Output an error message here, the page isn't in the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the code you have provided gives you the code you are looking for the homepage of 0218. The only error I see is you are not assigning the `$Code`. Your `$Code == '02'` should be `$Code = '02'`

Comment: Thank you so much, the double equal and declaring $Code first as suggested by @Satya fixed my issue.

Comment: declaring is very good practice, however shouldn't break your code. congrats